# Issue on Magento 2.1.7 Placing Order Errors

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.1.7, place-order

Place order error 400 on /rest/english/V1/carts/mine/payment-information magento 2

http://prntscr.com/os98gp

We are facing an error on a custom checkout, which on hit place order

- First, try, it cleans up all payment data.
- The second try, it throws this error, and throw the card error.

Did not find anything to help. Accept any solution but upgrade Magento to further versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the etc/webapi.xml yet? Seems that the issue is from authorization. You didn't set permission to the client

Answer (score 0):

vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php
You should use xdebug to debug function checkPermissions(). As Joe replied above, you might set wrong acl in webapi.xml. Debug will help you find the right issue.